# If I mounted /mnt/container/ to docker container will data get wiped on restart?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I must have copied a docker compose file that had volumes mounted to:

```
    volumes:
      - /mnt/containers/outline/container-data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
```

And after a host restart the database that was in there is empty.
Isn't that mount to internal container file system from the host system?

Has the host restart wiped the data?

To see the data that was mounted to host file persist after host server restart.
I do have some volumes that seam to be unassigned. Has docker created new volumes after restart and data is still on the host?

Comment: The `/mnt/containers` path implies this directory was mounted from somewhere before being bind mounted into the container. Was that drive mounted from the original source after the reboot? Was the container started after that drive was mounted?

Comment: Is it possible that I mounted an internal dir from a different container to this one? 
Isn't `/mnt/containers` something docker establishes on its own?

Comment: "Isn't /mnt/containers something docker establishes on its own?" Where do you see that behavior documented?